# Maven flex plugin looking for sourceDirectory during bootstrap (scm)

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have configured a project with `scm` that downloads a project and apply some goals.

The thing is that one of the plugins in the downloaded project is behaving in a way I don't expect. I'm pretty sure I'm missing something.

The project is downloaded to `target/it` folder.

The case is that `test-compile` phase execution it fails because cannot find `${baseDir}/target/it/src/main/java`.

When executing the project on its own is working nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible the variable isn't being parsed properly - sometimes maven tries to use the literal name instead. Try having it echo ${baseDir} at that step and check the output.